# Angular marker animations with setTimeout()

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

There is an example on marker drop animations, but looks like site doesn't work completely and its is impossible to view soruce of that example

[angular-google-map](http://allenhwkim.github.io/angularjs-google-maps/drawings.html#/marker-animations-iteration#marker-animations-iteration)

Is anybody know how to set timeout in html for that google maps implementation?

Comment: The link does not work.